# Unique representability of bounded distributive lattices

Tags: gn.general-topology, order-theory, duality, lattice-theory

[Priestley Duality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_theory_for_distributive_lattices) assigns to every bounded distributive lattice $L$ a compact totally order-disconnected topological space $P(L)$, also called a [Priestley space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priestley_space).

A poset $(P,\leq)$ is called (Priestley-) representable if there is a topology $\tau$ on $P$ such that $(P,\tau,\leq)$ is a Priestley space. Moreover, $(P,\leq)$ is called

1. *uniquely representable* if whenever there are topologies $\tau_1, \tau_2$ on $P$ such that $(P,\tau_i,\leq)$ is a Priestley space for $i=1,2$, we have $\tau_1=\tau_2$;
2. *weakly uniquely representable* if whenever there are topologies $\tau_1, \tau_2$ on $P$ such that $(P,\tau_i,\leq)$ is a Priestley space for $i=1,2$, the spaces $(P,\tau_1,\leq)$ and $(P,\tau_2,\leq)$ are order-homeomorphic (i.e. there is an automorphism $\varphi:(P,\tau_1) \to (P,\tau_2)$ that is also an order-isomorphism).

**Question.** Is there a weakly uniquely representable poset $(P,\leq)$ that is not uniquely representable?